# Use Windows PowerShell script to compile LaTeX files in parallel

Tags: loops, powershell, parallel-processing, latex

I can compile all the LaTeX files in a directory *sequentially* as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -include *.tex -name | ForEach-Object {
    lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=$pwd $_ } }
```

I would like to compile in *parallel,* two files at a time. I'm very new to Windows PowerShell, unfortunately, and I can't seem to find a good way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21520735/323582 - it suggests two ready to use solutions, both do processing in parallel and let you to specify the number of parallel jobs.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin, Using SplitPipeline, I now have something like this:
`    Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD -Include *.tex -Name | Split-Pipeline -Count 2 -Order {
        process {
            lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=$PWD $_ } }`

But the LaTeX compiler is complaining, "End of file on terminal...why?" Probably the LaTeX file name isn't being passed along properly. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It's because of `-Name` in `Get-ChildItem`. Remove `-Name` and use `$_.FullName` inside `process{...}`.

Comment: That works. Thanks! I've ended up answering my own question with thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer comes thanks to @RomanKuzmin and the SplitPipeline module.

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.tex | SplitPipeline -Count 2 {
    process {
        lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=$( $_.DirectoryName ) $_.FullName } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can kick off a new process asynchronously using the `Start-Process` cmdlet. If you do not specify the `-Wait` parameter, then the process will execute asynchronously.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\* -Include *.tex | `
ForEach-Object -Process { `
    Start-Process -FilePath lualatex -ArgumentList ('lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory={1} "{0}"' -f $PSItem.FullName, $pwd); `
    };
```

I have not tested this code, since I don't have the lualatex executable, but this should give you an idea of how it would work.

Comment: It looks like a good start.... Any ideas how to cap the number of spawned processes to two at a time?