# To performance improvement with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am Very new to Powershell scripting.I have script to get folder details from share network path as below. (eg.`\\INTBMCELB\Transport_Admin`)

```
$infile = 'C:\Paths\PathList.txt'

$outdir = 'C:\Export\'

foreach ($dir in (Get-Content $infile)) 

{

$outfile =  Join-Path $outdir($dir -split '\\')[-1]

$outfilecsv=$outfile+'.csv'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.* -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,@

{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Length}

} | Export-Csv -Path $outfilecsv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation}
```

In each network path which is reading from text file, contain lots of data. There are around 2500 share paths needs to read. Currently it takes around 2 days time to complete it. Can I improve the performance better?

Can I add any changes to above script which makes execution time less than the current total execution time?

Comment: The bottleneck is probably not in the script but in the amount of slow jobs. I would recommend to do this in parallel, especially if network paths are on different machines. Take a look at this answer for some tools: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21520735/323582

Comment: I also recommend to check for existence of `$dir` before doing `Get-ChildItem` on it. Because in PS v3.0+ on a missing path `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` searches in the current location instead (weird!). And if it is, say, C:\, it takes ages, indeed, and does not what one wants, more likely.